# MySQL / Lead Management / Campaign - Structure

Tags: php, mysql, crm

I'm just looking for the best way to structure the mysql tables. Let's say I have a table for CAMPAIGNS, and want to Auto-Generate a FORM based on the fields (I.e FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone).

But I want to make those fields edit-able, able to add more fields, etc, via a backend.

Is it best to have a 2nd table, that manages the FIELDS associated with CAMPAIGN 1, or to have the ability to edit that mysql TABLE direct?

If i were to use the 2nd table FIELDS, I'd be able to pull all fields from FIELDS where campaign ='2', show them, sort them, etc.

Or just edit the table direct, edit/add/delete fields direct to mysql table.

Will using the 2nd table to manage the fields, make everything else more complicated? (such as Exporting, instead of just php->mysql->export table, I need to run JOINs, etc).

What is everyone else doing these days, specifically for Campaign/Field Management, Form generating, etc. What are the major differences to using these 2 methods?

Any input appreciated,
Thanks
JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever let the program edit the tables directly (the one and only exception is of course creation and changing of temporary tables).

Especially do not even a millisecond think about a user who writes a column name.

You should identify two classes of fields on your table. Fields that modify the way you work with the data (these fields are business-relevant) and fields that are just the topping.

If you write business-relevant fields in a extra key-value-structure, you will get in trouble when you have to identify those values. So my advice: make those fields fixed table columns. And try to make as many fixed table columns as possible, I mean try to identify a core information set of a "CAMPAIGN". Those fields will be hard-coded in your form, but you could make them hideable, I mean you still can give the user a possibility to disable some of them for his needs. The other fields you should decorate with:

- id,
- the reference to CAMPAIGN,
- maybe a shortcut-NAME (program-oriented)
- a user-readable (internationalized)
- - name and
- - description,
- a base data type (which you can read in your program, like INT and STRING or even EMAIL),
- maybe a HTML type and class and style too, and a validation rule.

Comment: So, if I have 3x different industries with 10 fields, have 30 fields in table, but only show the 10 relevant to them?

I agree with everything else you've said. I already have that process built, where it has the campaign_id, name, desc, data_type, required, sort_order, etc. Just wanted to make sure there isn't a shortcut option.

Comment: Well, 30 columns is not a problem, and maybe not all 10 different columns are business relevant. Just find out which columns change work flows in your program, and try to put them into real strong columns. In the end you should even decorate those strong columns with type and description and validation, but I would not like to have parts in the program wich go `if (($columname == 'GENDER' or $columname == 'SEX') and value == 'company') then [company code]`. If it matters for the workflow, make it "real estate". ;-)